# How to render array from Express server to Pug and display it

Tags: node.js, pug

Need to render an array of users to pug template but it is not working.

users.pug

```
*
*
*
each user in userList
   tr
      td= user.name
      td= user.address
      td= user.age
*
*
*
```

server side code

```
logger.Debug(JSON.stringify(data));
res.render('users.pug', { userList:JSON.stringify(data)});
```

when i execute the server side code, the logger.Debug() statement generates the below:

```
[{"name":"ABC","address":"London","age":"30"}, {"name":"DEG","address":"USA","age":"25"},
{"name":"XYZ","address":"India","age":"35"}]
```

But rendering the same userList to pug is not working. It is rendering blanks

Please can anyone help and suggest some workaround here.

Comment: Don't stringify your data! Pug needs to see the array, not a string.

Comment: I tried that as well but still not working

Comment: Are the `*` really in your template or do they represent some other removed data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working version.

Two things I changed:

1. Added a `<table>` element to the template (and removed the `*` which I assume are fillers)
2. Pass the actual object to the template, not a string

```js
const pug = require('pug');

let template = `
table
  each user in userList
    tr
     td= user.name
     td= user.address
     td= user.age
`

const compiledFunction = pug.compile(template);
let data = [{"name":"ABC","address":"London","age":"30"}, {"name":"DEG","address":"USA","age":"25"},
{"name":"XYZ","address":"India","age":"35"}]


let html = compiledFunction({
  userList: data
});

document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = html
```

```html
<script src="https://pugjs.org/js/pug.js"></script>
<div id="data"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I removed the json.stringfy() and passed the array directly. It worked. Thanks agian.

Comment: In fact i have done that earlier but it was not working. And now after removing it again it worked. May be I might not have restarted the server. That could be the only case i can think of.

Answer (score 1):

In your server side ensure you have defined view-engine as pug and ensure the template files present under views folder at root level

example :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();    
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

Then try it out, it should work.

Note: As per Mark Meyer comments add table to your code, other wise it won't print the each tr in a single line.  Ensure you have #{} for dynamic variable substitution as well.

```
block content
   table  
    each user in userList
      tr.person
        td #{user.name} 
        td #{user.age}
```

Comment: Thanks Senthil. It is working without the #{} as well.